# Implementing HTML <form></form> Tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

Guys I want to implement this task

```
<form action="Delete" method="Post">      

</form>
```

but in a javascript function
How can I do this?
where Delete is my Controller name in CodeIgniter

Comment: What do you really mean? Do you want to add a form element in your page with javascript?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you want to accomplish

Comment: No 
i want to point to Delete Controller, using post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var html = '<form action="Delete" method="Post">...</form>';
  document.write(html);
</script>
```

Comment: will it point me to the Delete Controller in CodeIgniter

Comment: you have to set the correct url as value for the attribute "action". the url should start with a "/" or the domain, e.g. /delete

Answer (score 0):

Best guess based on the limited info - if you're looking to target specific code server side based on the form post you need to write something to interogate the post to the server and establish what action to take.

For example give the form a hidden field that is called action say & has a value delete. Then on the server for the post values check the value of the field & call your Delete function with the other form values you need.

Comment: Okay see
there is a select box containing values i.e insert, update, del etc if a user clicks on any of each option, the selected option should point me to the correct controller accordingly
here is a code for my select box
Select An Option:
        <select id="SelectOptions" style="color: black;" onchange="Action()"  >
        <option></option>
        <option >Insert</option>
        <option>Edit/Update</option>
        <option>Delete</option>
        <option>Truncate</option>        
        </select>
and what will be the java script function??
thanks :)